# Read ( Beautiful + Interesting ) stories

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word to express something that is beautiful and interesting at the same time, to use in this sentence:

> Read [term] stories

Can you help me find one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about **wonderful**?

Comment: Although this word is appropriate, it does seem a bit vague, if not slightly boring.

Answer (score 11):

There's not likely any word that precisely means those two things alone, but here are a few more to add to the list that I like:

- **Enthralling**
- **Spellbinding**
- **Mesmerising**

Comment: enthralling is a good one.

Answer (score 9):

How about **captivating**?

Comment: Read *captivating* stories. OMG i will not read any article/story with this headline. :D

Comment: Nothing wrong with the word itself, but somehow it just doesn't work in that context for me.

Answer (score 6):

With respect to stories, (or companions) "enchanting" might work.

Other possibilities along the same line:

- alluring
- bewitching

Answer (score 2):

How about **magnificent**?

Comment: I can imagine a magnificent yet boring story.

Comment: Yeah, I've read a lot of those...

Answer (score 2):

I prefer **engaging**, although Mike's **captivating** is a pretty close synonym and also good.

Comment: How does "engaging" imply "beautiful"?

Comment: See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/engaging and
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/engaging.

Answer (score 1):

How about **expressive**?

Answer (score 1):

How about..
**Amazing**, **Awesome**

Answer (score 1):

**Sublime** and **Delightful** are two words that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was **entrancing**.