# Synonym for a pleasurable coming-of-age experience

Tags: phrase-requests

I’m looking for a word, phrase, or comparison to mean a pleasurable, coming-of-age experience or discovery. Possibly with connotations of surprise or embarrassment.

I would really like to be able to compare something to a wet dream, but I suspect that is inappropriate for an audience of potential interviewers.

The context: “My discovery of atmospheric science was comparable to a wet dream.”

Comment: ... comparable to kissing someone (politer than having sex) for the first time?

Comment: I agree with @JAM: "comparable to a first kiss" could work; it connotes a sense of discovery, along with that coming-of-age experience you allude to. JAM, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @J.R. I don't think those innocent connotations will travel unblemished across to the OP's "audience of potential interviewers" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Enlightenment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enlightenment#Noun)* (“...achieving clarity of perception, reason and knowledge”), or *[epiphany](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epiphany#Noun)* (“An illuminating realization or discovery, often resulting in a personal feeling of elation, awe, or wonder”) probably are appropriate.

You might also say  “It was *[nirvana](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nirvana#Noun)*” (“state of paradise; heightened or great pleasure”) or  *[satori](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/satori#Noun)* (“A sudden inexpressible feeling of inner understanding or enlightenment”), and the interviewers that understand will be impressed.

Also see numerous suggestions at [Read ( Beautiful + Interesting ) stories](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1103).  These include *wonderful, captivating, enthralling, spellbinding, mesmerising, alluring, bewitching, engaging, magnificent, expressive, sublime, delightful, entrancing, amazing*, and *awesome*, as well as the bemusing advice, “There is no common English word which means beautiful and interesting at the same time.”

Comment: +1 for epiphanic. Exhilarating, stimulating, stirring, and inspiring are also related possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

> My discovery of atmospheric science was ***[orgasmic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orgasmic)***

noun: intense or paroxysmal excitement

---

I'm aware that isn't exactly appropriate either. Why not just say

> My discovery of atmospheric science was ***[enthralling](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enthralling?q=enthralling)***

adjective: capturing and holding one’s attention; fascinating

Answer (score 2):

Further to comments, here's my suggestion:

> My discovery of atmospheric science was comparable to a first kiss.

Answer (score 0):

We might be making this more freudian than it needs to be. How about "my discovery of atmospheric science was a real eye-opener." It brought my mind to life. Made me realise what I wanted to do.